# Echo Regex match group in bash command line

Tags: regex, bash, terminal

How to print Regex match group value from terminal command line?

I'm trying to echo the process ID of a running port using

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

But this outputs to a string of details like this

```
node    1234 myname   12u  IPv6 0xf1c950b487699d0      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

I need to echo out `1234` alone, so that I can kill that PID using `kill` command.

I used grep -E, but I'm unable to print the capture group. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk for this:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | awk '/LISTEN/{print $2}'
```

`/LISTEN/` will execute this when line has `LISTEN` in it and `$2` will be 2nd field in input which is your process id.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. But I'm not able to pipe that `kill`. Do you think of any reason? Trying to do `lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | awk '/LISTEN/{print $2}' | kill -9`

Comment: Use: `lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | awk '/LISTEN/{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`